# Change Color Using Metafields

Tags: css, shopify, customization

I want to try and change Specific  just so I can customize my dawn store more

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6n3he.png) I am not exactly sure where that is

I tried changing product-variant.liquid but to no avail I thought it would change but it didnt I am not sure why I cant get it to work on my shopify store

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below instruction :

1. Add a metafield to the product variant using the Shopify admin. You
   can do this by navigating to the product variant, scrolling down to
   the "Metafields" section, and clicking "Add a metafield".

   In the "Namespace" field, enter a unique identifier for the
   metafield. For example, "my-shop-color".

   In the "Key" field, enter a key for the metafield. For example,
   "color".

   In the "Value" field, enter the color value you want to use. For
   example, "#FF0000" for red.

   Save the metafield.

   In your product-variant.liquid file, you can use the following code
   to retrieve the value of the metafield:

```html
{% assign color = variant.metafields.my-shop-color.color %}
```

You can then use the color variable to set the background color or any other styling for the variant. For example:

```html
<div style="background-color: {{ color }};">
    {{ variant.title }}
</div>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: So I named it namespace Color.color made color #FF0000 red in metafield options product dropdown the code at added it at the end {% assign color = variant.metafields.Color.color %} but it still hasnt changed I added it to product metafield

Comment: I am a bit confused about vaule do u mean iun product metafield where u can change the color variants or is there option to add value

Comment: I think you need to use variant meta fields instead of products, variant metafileds are for specific variants and are easy to map instead of product meta fields.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/8LxLWdx this is what I did but didnt get it to work

Comment: with metaobjects things are complicated now. You need to user variant.metafields.<<your name space>>.<<your metafield name>>.value. But this too will give some gid://shopify/<<what not>> and at least i am not able to resolve it. Any help will be appriciated.